How do these two definitions apply to the same term?
Tushar's answer to this question (What is an equivalent?) gives two definitions for an "equivalent"


An equivalent (symbol: officially equiv; unofficially but often Eq) is the amount of a substance that reacts with (or is equivalent to) an arbitrary amount of another substance in a given chemical reaction

And 
the equivalent is the amount of a substance needed to do one of the following:react with or supply one mole of hydrogen ions (H+
) in an acid-base reaction.react with or supply one mole of electrons in a redox reaction


I do not understand how these two definitions are the same and how they make it so that

1 equiv of a substance reacts with exactly 1
equiv of another substances to produce 1
equiv of each product

Can anyone help me see why these statements all describe the same thing and why they are true?

They are not the same. The latter is the special case of the former, limiting itself to acid-base and redox reactions, with the explicitly chosen  reference equivalent H+ or an electron. But they share the same principle - stoichiometry of chemical reactions.

An equivalent is defined in regards to reaction or class of reactions with some degree of arbitrariness. Say, you have a reaction of type
$\ce{x A + y B = ...}$
In here you have a choice

declare that equivalent of A is 1. Then equivalent of B is y/x
declare that equivalent of B is 1. Then equivalent of A is x/y
declare that equivalent of A is 1/y and equivalent of B is 1/x
come with something else

There is nothing objectively dictating a specific choice here, only your convenience.
Often, equivalent is defined on basis of some kind of half-reaction (redox, acid-base or something else). Say, you have reaction of molecular oxygen with phosphorous.
$\ce{4P + 5 O_2 = 2 P2O5}$
In this case you can write half-reactions
$\ce{P = P^{+5} + 5 e^{-}}$
$\ce{O2 = 2 O^{-2} - 4 e^{-}}$
since the reaction is balanced on basis of electrons, it is 'natural' to define an equivalent as part of molecule taking or providing one electon, i.e. the equivalent of phosphorous is 1/5 and equivalent of molecular oxygen is 1/4.
Acid-base reactions are similar, but their the natural balancing particle is acidic hydrogen, thus the equivalent of, say, sulfuric acid usually would be 1/2.
The concept of equivalent is useful in calculations. You can say: "Since sulfuric acid is equivalent to 2 protons, I can replace it everywhere in my calculation with its equivalent and forget about this pesky digit '2' I can easily miss. Thus instead of molar mass and molar concentration of sulfuric acid I will use molar mass and molar concentration of its equivalent."
In response to comments
People tend to mix equivalent mass (or weight), equivalent particle (no unit) or amount of equivalents (usually measured in mols). Depending on context and beliefs of the person speaking, either can be short-handed as 'equivalent'.

No, permeakra ! You state that "the equivalent of sulfuric acid is $1/2$". No ! The equivalent of sulfuric acid is $49$ g (or $49$ g/equiv). $1/2$ is not the equivalent of sulfuric acid. $1/2$  is the ratio equivalent/molar mass, because the equivalent of sulfuric acid is $49$ g, and its molar mass is $98$ g/mol.

permeakrea, I am afraid you are using a different concept of equivalents. Equivalent is an archaic unit used in analytical chemistry.

@Maurice 49g would be molar mass of the equivalent of sulfuric acid or equivalent weight. Amount of equivalents is typically measured in mols.

@AChem Equivalent certainly is not a unit, archaic or otherwise.

Equivalent concept pre-dates moles etc. Equivalent and gram-equivalent have had a very specific meaning in chemical analysis-long before electron or mole were known.

The first definition is not precise enough, specially the words "react with an arbitrary amount". "An arbitrary amount" is not precise enough. It should be mentioned "react with one mole of Hydrogen atom or Hydrogen ion, or electron". The definition "one mole" is fundamental, and must be mentioned.

Looking up any word in a GOOD dictionary or online can be like a trip into the Twilight Zone; try it. Chemistry sometimes uses equivalence lightly hence the first definition. An example of this use is on the food labeling in the USA. Fats are equivalent to 9 Kcal/gram, Carbs and protein are equivalent to 4 Kcals/gram. Not equal but equivalent.
There are 2 precise definitions that are common. The first is in acid-base reactions, specifically the reaction between hydrogen ion H+ or H3O+ and OH-: H+ + OH- = H2O. Since it is a one on one reaction and some acids have more than one H  and some bases more than one OH it is easier to define the equivalent weight as the weight of the chemical that has one mole of H or OH. The practice has crept into some other ionic reactions so attention is necessary.
The second use is in electrochemistry. Half reaction potentials are given in volts/electron = joules/coulomb of electricity regardless of how the half reaction is written. The free energy change for one Faraday of electricity is for one mole of electrons. To obtain molar free energy changes the total number of electrons must be included.  DeltaG = EnF.
